# Append a link doesn't apply the style correctly

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, append, margin

here's my first question on SO, hope I searched enough to post! This is my first fully coded project, I may not know everything.

I'm trying to append a styled link into html with Jquery.
The append action worsk, but it's seem the appended link isn't styled correctly : margins aren't the ones specified in my css. Links created manually with the same style are ok, margins are good.

I'll bet code and result are better than words, so here is my project

http://codepen.io/AristideBH/pen/ZGzPmR/ Live demo on Codepen

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <a class='link'>content</a>
  <a class='link'>content</a>
  <a class='link'>content</a>
  ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.link{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0.4vw;}
```

Jquery

```
$('button').on( "click", function() {
   var link = "<a class='link'>Added link</a>";
   $( ".container" ).append(link);
});
```

Basically you'll see the problem by clicking a few times on the + button, on the top right. The initial links are well spaced, but the one added by Jquery just have way thinner side margins.
I tried to change the unit of the margin, or go to a fixed width (not ideal, responsive design)
I saw this problem on both Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Hope I was clear enough, and you'll have answers for me ;)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try using a finite unit for the margin or %

Comment: Should have precised, I already tried that, and the problem's still the same with a fixed width, or any unit :/

Comment: O sorry it's because you have them as inline block. When jquery adds the links, it probably does not have a space between each link which causes the issue

Comment: Nothing is really wrong, this is the normal way inline-block behaves. If you have white space in between the item then that space will be displayed (original links) but if there is no white space(added links) then you won't see a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the links are display `inline-block` and there is white space in the original html code. So there is that extra space in the original links. When jquery adds the links, there is no white space between each link and that's why you see them closer together.

The fix

I would suggest you update your original html to not have a space between the links like so

```
<a class="link" id="fb">
    <h3>Link 1</h3>
</a><a class="link">
    <h3>Link 2
</h3></a>
```

or

```
<a class="link" id="fb"><h3>Link 1
</h3></a><!--

--><a class="link"><h3>Link 2
</h3></a>
```

Now adjust your margins to make them fit well and this will solve your issue

The fix with jquery

To add the space in jquery it is extremely easy

```
$('button').on( "click", function() {
   var link = "<a class='link'>Added link</a> ";
   $( ".container" ).append(link);
});
```

Comment: Well I didn't excpected a so simple answer ! but that works !

Comment: Yes you can easily, notice the extra space at the end of the anchor in the updated answer

Comment: @zfrisch That worked too, and I didn't have to find another value for my margin. Thanks!